# Webpack failed to compile, trying to integrate a searchbox component

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to integrate [react-search-box](https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/react-search-box) to an existing project but when starting I get:

```
ERROR in ./~/react-search-box/dist/styles.css
Module parse failed: C:\Users\User\gitcvs\project1\node_modules\react-search-box\dist\styles.css Unexpected token (3:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

This is my webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
      }
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    port: 8078
  }
};
```

Searching on the web seems to indicate I need to add a css loader in webpack? Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you must install via npm css-loader and style-loader, then add his rule to your weback.config.js under **module.rules** field

```
module.exports: {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I got the syntax right, is that correct: https://pastebin.com/raw/7T0GApc9 because I still get the error

Comment: sorry, maybe this could help? [babbel issue](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/173)